# Possible to use :hover with Foundation for Emails?

Tags: html, css, hover, zurb-foundation, html-email

I'm designing an email newsletter using Foundation for Emails. I know that inlining a hover style doesn't really work. However, having hover styles would really add a nice touch to my newsletter. I'm wondering if Foundation found a way to make this work, and if there is anything I can do to get these styles in my email.

Comment: Your are missing the core principle here: email clients are required to make all links visible, in order to make it impossible to conceal a link in normal text. Email should be considered an advanced text message, not a web page. The only allowed html and css methods are those which cannot possibly be abused, and this is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `:hover` in the style sheet, global or specific:

```
a:hover, .linkname:hover {
  background: #ff0000 !important;
  border: 1px solid: #ff0000 !important;
}
```

Beyond that, in the SASS version, there's a section to declare all of your href values:

```
$anchor-text-decoration: none;
$anchor-color: $primary-color;
$anchor-color-visited: $anchor-color;
$anchor-color-hover: darken($primary-color, 10%);
$anchor-color-active: $anchor-color-hover;
```

You can modify: `$anchor-color-hover: darken($primary-color, 10%);` by adjusting the values or just putting in the color you wish to use instead.

Some email clients do not work with `:hover`, but many do:

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/selectors/hover/

Good luck.

Comment: Since some email clients strips out embedded/external styles, this is not a reliable solution.

Comment: Some clients will not work with `:hover`. The ones that do not will gracefully fail. It works with gmail, Apple, IOS and fails with some gmail mobile clients and Outlook. It's a great solution.